# Analyzing an asp.net site with ndepend

Tags: asp.net, ndepend

I'm trying to analyze a web site (built with asp.net) with ndepend.

If a take a look at the CQL queries about "unused code / dead code", the tool cites almost all my methods (including the onload, onprerender, ...), which is obviously wrong.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to have a better result ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exception790, the methods you are quoting onload, onprerender... are indeed never **statically** used in the code but are **dynamically** used (at runtime) by the ASP.NET infrastructure.

NDepend being a **static** analyzer, it can't anticipate **dynamic** calls.

Answer (score 5):

As I can see from NDepend [**FAQ**](http://www.ndepend.com/FAQ.aspx) *(look for "**How can I analyse my ASP.NET application with NDepend?**")*, you'll have to precompile your web-site and analyze it after that. There's how-to there.